# Tensorflow: switch between CPU and GPU [Windows 10]

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

How can I quickly switch between running tensorflow code with my CPU and my GPU?

**My setup:**

OS = Windows 10

Python = 3.5

Tensorflow-gpu = 1.0.0

CUDA = 8.0.61

cuDNN = 5.1

I saw a post suggesting something about setting `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0` but I don't have this variable in my environment (not sure if it's because I'm running windows or what) but if I do set it using something like `os.environ` it doesn't effect how tensorflow runs code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the environment variable `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1` you will use the CPU only. If you don't set that environment variable you will allocate memory to all GPUs but by default only use GPU 0. You can also set it to the specific GPU you want to use. `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0` will only use GPU 0.

This environment variable is created by the user, it won't exist until you create it. You need to set the variable before tensorflow is imported (usually that is before you start your script).

Comment: Worked perfectly with -1. But, I'd like to switch without having to re-import tensorflow. Is that possible?

Comment: Programmatically you do it with `tf.Device`

Comment: Yup! `tf.Device()` was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Hello, how did you set the environment variable ? i'm using vscode and when i do this :
set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1 & python -m "file.py" 
it doesn't work
even : set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="" & python -m "file.py"  doesn't work in cmd

Comment: `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1` @DetchKing

Comment: when i do this : `python -m "bootstrap.run"`

it works
when i do this : it also works : ` set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1 `

but the problem is this:  `set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1 python -m "bootstrap.run"`

Comment: Run `python -c "import os; print(os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'])"` if you don't see CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES in your environment variables something basic is wrong with python and you should open a different question to deal with that issue. This sounds like an environment variable issue.